# Timeout error while batch geocoding with google maps API in python

Tags: python, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I'm new to the Google Maps API and I'm not sure why this code isn't working. I have a list of 80 landmarks in a csv file that im trying to retrieve the lon and lat coordinates to.

I believe something may be wrong with how I'm connecting to the API. From my understanding, I should have 2,500 free requests per day but I'm receiving a timeout error that makes me think I've already reached my limit.

Here is a snapshot of my dashboard 
[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as  pd
import googlemaps

# IMPORT DATASET
df = pd.read_csv('landmarks.csv')

# GOOGLE MAPS API KEY
gmaps_key = googlemaps.Client(key = 'MY KEY')

df['LAT'] = None
df['LON'] = None

for i in range (0, len(df), 1):
    geocode_result = gmaps_key.geocode(df.iat[i,0])
    try:
        lat = geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lat']
        lon = geocode_result[0]['geometry']['location']['lon']
        df.iat[i, df.comlumns.get_loc('LAT')] = lat
        df.iat[i, df.comlumns.get_loc('LON')] = lon
    except:
        lat = None
        lon  = None

print(df)
```

Error Message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\JGrov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py",
>   line 253, in _request
>       result = self._get_body(response)   File "C:\Users\JGrov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py",
>   line 276, in _get_body
>       raise googlemaps.exceptions._RetriableRequest() googlemaps.exceptions._RetriableRequest
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:/Users/JGrov/Google
>   Drive/pythonProjects/Megalith Map/googleMapsAPI_Batch_Megaliths.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       geocode_result = gmaps_key.geocode(df.iat[i,0])   File "C:\Users\JGrov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py",
>   line 356, in wrapper
>       result = func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\JGrov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\geocoding.py",
>   line 68, in geocode
>       return client._request("/maps/api/geocode/json", params)["results"]   File
>   "C:\Users\JGrov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py",
>   line 260, in _request
>       extract_body, requests_kwargs, post_json)   File "C:\Users\JGrov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py",
>   line 260, in _request
>       extract_body, requests_kwargs, post_json)   File "C:\Users\JGrov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py",
>   line 260, in _request
>       extract_body, requests_kwargs, post_json)   [Previous line repeated 9 more times]   File
>   "C:\Users\JGrov\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py",
>   line 203, in _request
>       raise googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout() googlemaps.exceptions.Timeout

Any help on this matter would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Having a similar problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I do not believe I did because I would have posted back here.